# Struts 2: Navigation of pages through Link

Tags: struts2

I am using struts2 . I want that after clicking on link on 1st page it should go to 2nd jsp page.How to do that.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remember one thing since you are working with MCV2 based platform so its never advised to go from a `jsp` page to another `jsp` page directly which is being treated as bad practice.(you are not going through proper request cycle)

Request should go through Actions.Struts2 provide a convenient way to help you for such use-cases.

If in your struts config file you do not provide any `Action` class name framework will create an action class for you on the fly with return type as `SUCCESS`. This is all you need to do:

```
<action name=gotoJSP2>
 <result>/page2.jsp</result>
</action>
```

This is all you need and you are good to go.

Though you can go from one `JSP` to Another but make sure you have no Struts2 tags and any such framework dependence since going form one `JSP` to another means not calling Struts2 Dispatcher filter and not letting framework to do required work to serve you.

Comment: Ya thanks.It's Working. I just gave one link to Registration page and on previous page jsp page gave the hyperlink for that page.